# How do I ensure that a string containing uft8 characters is correctly written to mysql in my C program?

Tags: c, utf-8, mariadb

I'm trying to insert a string into my MariaDB database which contains a Unicode character which is greater than 128, namely 177, `±`.

```
wchar_t wcs = L"INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(9,14063,'\261\065\061\067\071')";
```

using `wctombs`:

```
int ret;
ret = wctombs(querybuffer, wcs, 60);
```

`ret` is -1, which apparently means that there is a wide character that does not correspond to a valid multibyte character.

I've modified my code as per the suggestions from John Bollinger (much appreciated):

> ```
> while(txt[i])
> {
>   c=cleaveMControl(txt,&i,j);
>   if(c){
>     if(c<128)
>       query[j++]=c;
>     else{
>       query[j++]=92;
>       query[j++]=92;
>       sprintf(query+j,"u00%x",c);
>       j=strlen(query);
>     }
>   }
> }
> query[j++]=39;
> query[j++]=41;
> query[j++]=59;
> query[j]=0;
> mysql_query(sqlconnect,query);
> ```

This produces:

```
MariaDB [D8]> select * from text where eID=14063;
+---------+-------+------------+
| drawing | eID   | txt        |
+----------+-------+------------+
|       9 | 14063 | \u00b15179 |
+---------+-------+------------+
```

I'm expecting to see '±5179'.

I'm still battling with this. Thanks to John Bollinger, I can assign a utf8 character thus:
wchar_t c:
char uni[5];
uni[i++]=192+((c>>6)&15);
uni[i++]=128+(c&63);
This gives me the mysql string: INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(9,14063,'\302\261\065\061\067\071');

There is no error, but the value inserted into the database is without the ± character:
+----------+-------+------------+
|        9 | 14063 | 15179      |
+----------+-------+------------+

Comment: Can you have UTF-8 source for this? Would avoid the manual encoding there.

Comment: Why are you going through a wide string literal and `wctombs()`?  There are multiple better ways to get a UTF-8 encoded string, especially if (but not only if) you can rely on even a remotely recent version of C.

Comment: And why are you using octal escapes for (it appears) ordinary decimal digits?

Comment: How are you writing to mysql? `insert a string into my MariaDB` How do you do that? Inserting into mariadb is the important part. You should use `mysql_escape_string`. `ret is -1, which apparently means that there` Did you set locale? For conversions you have to set locale. Please post full program, including all `#include`s.

Comment: Be sure to establish the connection as being utf8mb4, or do `SET NAMES utf8mb4` right after connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I ensure that a string containing uft8 characters is correctly written to mysql in my C program?

To begin, this is wrong:

> ```
> wchar_t wcs=L"INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(9,14063,'\261\065\061\067\071')"
> ```

Your compiler should be warning you about assigning a pointer to an integer (and a narrower one at that) without a cast.  It should also be complaining here:

> ```
> ret=wctombs(querybuffer,wcs,60);
> ```

... about converting the other direction.  If you are not getting such warnings then either turn up your compiler's warning level or get a better compiler.

This definition of `wcs` would be more likely to work:

```
const wchar_t *wcs = L"INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(9,14063,'\261\065\061\067\071')";
```

The main thing is that you need to declare `wcs` as a pointer, not an individual `wchar_t`.  Adding `const` offers some protection against accidentally trying to modify the contents, which you must not do.

---

But if you can assume at least C11, then

- you can portably define a string that is encoded in-memory via UTF-8 by using a UTF-8 string literal.
- in any string literal, you can use "universal character names" to refer to characters by their Unicode code point values.

Putting that together, in C11 or later you can just say:

```
const char *s = u8"INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(9,14063,'\u00b1" u8"5171')";
```

to get your wanted UTF-8 encoded bytes, regardless of any consideration of source and execution character sets.

By the way, it's not necessary to split that into two literals as I did, but doing so helps to clarify that the universal character name `\u00b1` does not continue on into the subsequent digits of the string.  (Note: there are 8-digit universal character names, too, but they start with `\U` instead of `\u`).

---

If you cannot assume at least C11 then you would probably still be better off skipping the wide string literal, instead inserting the UTF-8 encoding directly for the single character you need:

```
const char *s = "INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(9,14063,'\302\261" "5171')";
```

That does rely on an ASCII- (and UTF8-)compatible encoding for the characters of the execution basic character set, but that's a relatively safe bet, and a weaker requirement than is needed for your wide-string variant to work.

Comment: Thanks, John for your considered input.In point of fact the wcs assignment was just to show what the wchar_t array contained. Each character in the 'txt' value string was actually individually assigned. My compiler is C11 compliant so I will take your comments on board and have another go.

Comment: Fair enough, @DaveCoventry, but in that case I *really* don't see how it makes sense go through `wchar_t` and `wctombs()`.  You should be able to simply assign the appropriate code sequences (most of them just one unit) directly to your destination array.  Now that I think about it, it would probably make sense to declare it as an array of `unsigned char` instead of `char`, but you should be able to use that with mariadb, possibly with the help of a cast to `char *`.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `unsigned char` doesn't solve the problem: `$6 = (unsigned char *) 0x55555557ae90 "INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(9,14063,'\261\065\061\067\071');"`. The mysql error is "Incorrect string value: '\xD81200' for column `D8`.`text`.`txt` at row 1"

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood, @DaveCoventry.  First, you need to put the bytes of the UTF-8 encoding into the string, as shown above (though I suggest switching to hex escapes from octal for ease of maintenance).  The debugger output shows that you have not done that correctly.  The UTF-8 encoding of character U+00B1 is the two bytes `0xC2 0xB1`.  Second, the point about `unsigned char` was that you might want to declare the array itself to have elements of type `unsigned char`.  In that case, your compiler might complain about a signedness mismatch unless you cast the pointer to `char *`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've been chasing my tail on this, it's easy to become confused.